# React upgrade: "this" visibility in getDefaultProps

Tags: function, reactjs, upgrade

I am upgrading some older react component I inherited (v0.10.0) to work with the latest version of react (v0.14.8).

The following scenario stopped working:

```
// within a react component    
onClick: function() {
    // DO SOMETHING
}

getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
        someProp: 'prop',
        onClick: this.onClick
    }
}
```

This is easily resolved moving the code into an anonymous function, like the following:

```
getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
        someProp: 'prop',
        onClick: function() { 
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
}
```

**My question is**: why has the visibility of 'this' changed at that level and what's the best way to refactor this code? And what if I had-to/wanted-to use 'this' at that level?

Any help appreciated, as a disclaimer I am a react super-beginner!

Answer (score 1):

[The result of `getDefaultProps()` is shared across all instances of a component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getdefaultprops). That means that the result can't rely on any particular instance of the component. The reason it changed is likely because of the performance benefit from caching, although I can't say for sure.

As for refactoring the code, I'm not sure there's a silver-bullet here. From my perspective what you currently have seems like an anti-pattern. Props are meant to be passed in by consumers that have no knowledge of the inner workings of the component, so it seems odd that a default value for a prop would depend on the inner workings. Without knowing exactly what you're doing, I would say your best bet is to just use `null` as the default value for the prop, then check the value at runtime when you do have access to the `this` context.

```
handleSomeAction() {
    if (!this.props.onClick) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```